# Share JavaScript code between Twilio functions

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I have a Twilio serverless app that contains several functions. Several of the functions have code that is similar that I have extracted out into a separate file that can be used by the loaded and used by the functions.

This works if I run things locally with `twilio serverless:start`, but fails when I deploy to Twilio and try using the endpoints from their. On Twilio the functions fail with the message `Cannot find module '<path to module>' \nRequire stack ...`

functions (two files like this):

```js
const share = require('shared-code');
```

`shared-code.js`:

```js
exports.helperFn = function() {}
```

**How can I easily share JavaScript code between Twilio functions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can find the [path of a Function here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/client?code-sample=code-retrieve-the-path-for-a-function&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=default). Then use that path in the file in which you want to reference code from another file:

```js
let path = Runtime.getFunctions()['function-path'].path; //example: Runtime.getFunctions()['api/identity'].path;
```

where the Function path is the Function name after the `/` in the URL.

Then to [use that code from a Function in a different Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/client?code-sample=code-include-code-from-a-function&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=default), you could require this

```js
let module = require(path);
```

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thank you, helped in our project as well! Had a file in a folder common with the private extension eg. /common/file-name.private.js. Accessed it just fine like "/common/file-name"